# Can I remove noncluster index on key which is same cluster key if not being used?

Tags: indexing, foreign-keys, sql-server-2019

[image: DB Diagaram]

I think diagram itself is self-explanatory. All events get store in "Events" table and according to type of event extra parameters get stored into Event(n) tables.

Design is kind of same for all Event(n) tables.
ID column in Event(n) table is PK as well FK of Events table.

The above tables are Very Large Tables. I've main one Events table and at least 20-25 multiple Event(n) tables.

Question is, Can I remove noncluster index on ID key which is also to be cluster key if not being used, e.g. no seek, scan and lookup in or even rarely seek compared to lots of updates?

Also in general, is it okay to remove noncluster index on foreign key if it is not being used at all?

Comment: "I think diagram itself is self-explanatory." - it is not. Add the DDL (create table statements with constraints and indexes) to your question. Images will attract down votes.

Comment: I think that this question is more suitable for [Stack Exchange Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can safely remove the non-clustered index assuming the following below.  there's no need to have two indexes,  the execution query would always use the clustered anyway.

1. You have one-to-one relationships.
2. Main Table name should be EVENT, not EVENTS (since each row is an event)
3. In EVENT you would have a PK CLUSTERED INDEX with EventID INT
4. In EVENT1, EVENT2, etc. you would have ForeignKey referencing EventID, You should use a CLUSTERED INDEX on this foreign key.  The column should also be unique.